# custom font is not working in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

After saving the fonts in my assets folder of my project I linked it by the command `react-native link`
the links were installed and I cross checked the installation in my `android>src>main>assets>fonts` and everything was fine there too and I expected to get the custom font using the styling `fontFamily: 'Coda-Heavy'` but I didn't get the required custom font in run

Also please refer to this link I have posted it as an issue in react native:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15266

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you do this steps?

1 Create folder `/assets/fonts` in main root

2 Put this in your `package.json`

```
“rnpm”: {
   “assets”: [“./assets/fonts”]
}
```

3 And then run `react-native link` again

4 Your font will be copied to `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`

Comment: @AdarshSreeram have you check the full name property of your font? try change your font file name into your font full name property. Although android use filename, but maybe you can give it a try?

Comment: @AdarshSreeram have you try this also? https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/add-a-custom-font-to-your-react-native-app

Comment: any other solutions ??

Comment: @AdarshSreeram I have tried it and it is working, so I don't know any other solution :'D. I follow this, except the part 3, I just type `./assets/fonts` https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/add-a-custom-font-to-your-react-native-app

Comment: I too have tried the way you do it but it's not working for me

Comment: @AdarshSreeram do you mind share the project? I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Removing `fontWeight` will resolve this for you.