# How can I make the custom navigation bar transparent in RNRF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I have tried all the options in react-native-router-flux like: `navigationBarStyle` or `navTransparent` and also
`navigationBarStyle={[STYLES.navBar]}`
all of these are not working while trying to make the custom navigation bar transparent Is there any ways to make it transparent using react-navigation and should I change from react-native-router-flux to react-navigation to do this I have posted it as an issue in Git Hub 
here is the link :[Github issue #2132](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2132)

since I found it hard using react-navigation I have switched to RNRF is there any solution to make the custom navBar transparent other than switching from RNRF to RN or is it a bug in RN

[image: this is what my navBar looks like now]

here's the code that i use in my NavBar.js file :

```js
import {
 View, Image, StatusBar, TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar />
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Actions.pop()}>
      <Image
    source={require('./Images/back-arrow.png')}
    style={styles.backarrowStyle} />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

      <Image
  source={require('./Images/help.png')}
  style={styles.helpStyle} />


  <Image
source={require('./Images/setting.png')}
style={styles.settingStyle} />
    </View>
</View>
    );
  }

}
const styles = {
  backgroundStyle: {
 backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  backarrowStyle: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: 55,
    height: 55,
    left: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
  },
  helpStyle: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      left: 210,
      justifyContent: 'flex-end',
      position: 'relative'

  },
  settingStyle: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  position: 'relative',
  left: 210
}
};


export default NavBar;
```

and this is my Router.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import MainScreen from './components/MainScreen';
import ChallengeScreen from './components/ChallengeScreen';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import Toss from './components/Toss';

const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
<Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="homeScreen" component={MainScreen} hideNavBar={1} />
    <Scene
     key="screen2" component={ChallengeScreen}
     navBar={NavBar}
        />
    <Scene
     key="screen3" component={Toss}
   navBar={NavBar}
        />
</Scene>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default RouterComponent;
```

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but I am not at all clear on what this question is asking.  I think it would be helpful if you reviewed [ask], and tried to restructure your question more clearly, with proper formatting, code samples, and a clear explanation of what you are expecting and what you are getting, plus any error messages you may be seeing.

Comment: I think i have made it very clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is set semi-transparent navbar by setting navbar opacity in navigationBarStyle

```
<Scene key="scene2" component={ChallengeScreen} 
       navigationBarStyle={{opacity:0.3}}/>
```

but the problem is the whole navbar including left and right button will be inherit the opacity. I recommend just set hidenavbar={true} and implement custom navbar in the scene component. For eg: in Scene2 component (ChallengeScreen)

```
 render() {
     const customNavbar = {
       <View style={{position:'absolute', top:0, flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between', backgroundColor:'transparent', padding:10}}>
           <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>Left Button</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
           <Text>Title</Text>
           <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text>Right Button</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    }

   return () {
     <View style={{flex:1}}>
         {customNavbar}
         <View></View>
     </View>
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks @digit there was a very small mistake I didn't apply styles  in  the correct view your solution helped so much since I got clear with the structure of navBar  in transparent now :)

Comment: hey @digit can you answer this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407315/custom-font-is-not-working-in-react-native/45407464?noredirect=1#comment77866602_45407464)

Comment: Hi, is it about custom font? I found you one the link in the SO , https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/react-native/4341/custom-fonts#t=201708020629584160906

Comment: yes its about custom font but i tried all that but its not working